# Is there an "official" translation of Malcom X's You can't hate the roots of a tree and not hate the tree"?

Tags: translation

Malcom X once said:

> You can't hate the roots of a tree and not hate the tree. You can't hate Africa and not hate yourself.

It is a fairly well known quote.

- Are there any “official” translations of this quote? (Not Google translate, etc.)

Comment: iciba (official?)： 你不能恨一棵树的根，而不恨树。你不能恨非洲，也不恨自己。

Comment: Only official statements, such as government regulations and UN statements, get official translations.  Maybe you meant to ask whether there is any already published translation?

Comment: well known example of "official translation":阿拉伯语：

    لَا إِلٰهَ إِلَّا الله مُحَمَّدٌ رَسُولُ الله‎

罗马化：

    lā ʾilāha ʾillā-llāh, muḥammadun rasūlu-llāh

中文翻译：

    “万物非主，唯有真主。穆罕默德，是主使者。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such sayings have their culture background and only Malcom X himself could tell whether a translation is right or not.

"背祖忘宗" or "數典忘祖" may carry a similar meaning but does not have the same context.  Not to say creative translations like "惱根怎可不惱樹, 厭鄉也該厭自己".

Comment: Or even shorter: 惱根該惱樹, 厭鄉當厭己

Answer (score 0):

I think should be

> > 你不能恨一棵树的根，而不恨树。你不能恨非洲，**却**不恨自己。

It's literal translation, I don't know whether there is a more elegant way like translated into Chinese idiom.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are many chinese saying

- 人穷怪屋基、屋漏怪瓦稀
- 人醜不要怪父母，人窮不要怪政府

Comment: Different meanings. Not a translation of, said, quote by any means.

Comment: I think @user3306356 you are not a chinese? This is a very good translation.